# Using local npm libraries with es6, babel, and webpack

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, babeljs, babel-loader

I'm running into an issue that appears to be due to my lack of understanding with webpack. I have created a file structure that looks like this:

```
|-serverless-cloud-functions
||-my-local-libs
|||-twilioClient
||-service1
||-service2
```

twilioClient is a library that I made, that needs to be included in service1 and service2. Because of limitations with the serverless framework, you can not bundle files outside of the service, so the only option (I think) is to use a `npm install ../my-local-libs/twilioClient` from inside a service folder. This works for installing the module, but now it resides in node_modules. Currently, I am using webpack and babel as well.

I believe my root issue is that my webpack config looks like this:

```
const slsw = require("serverless-webpack");
const nodeExternals = require("webpack-node-externals");

module.exports = {
    entry: slsw.lib.entries,
    target: "node",

    externals: [nodeExternals()],

    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: "babel-loader",
                exclude: /node_modules/
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

Which excludes my es6 `twilioClient` lib, because it is in the `node_modules` folder.

I saw a couple people suggest that this was the way to accomplish 'exclude everything in node modules besides `twilioClient`':

```
module.exports = {
    entry: slsw.lib.entries,
    target: "node",

    externals: [nodeExternals()],

    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: "babel-loader",
                exclude: /node_modules\/(?!(twilioClient))/
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

But this did not work in my case. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to exclude `twilioClient`, you could use Babel to compile it separately. Something like this (in the `twilioClient` directory):

```
npx babel src --out-dir lib
```

In `twilioClient/package.json`, you could then set `main` to `lib/index.js` instead of `src/index.js` so that importing scripts will get the compiled version:

```
"main": "lib/index.js",
```

Then instead of hosting `twilioClient` alongside `service1` and `service2`, you could just push it to github, and install it in each client using npm:

`npm install --save http://github.com/your_github_username/twilioclient.git`

Now you can use `twilioClient` as if it were any other npm dependency.

Comment: Awesome! Never thought about using babel separately. I ended up keeping my npm libraries where they were, but everything works now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered a similar problem of using local common package with babel.

If you would like to not change the `main` since you also actively edit the package and do not want to run the build each time you make a change, then you should use the below `babel.config.js`

```
module.exports = function(api) {
  api.cache(true);

  const plugins = [
    '@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs',
  ];

  return {
    plugins,
    ignore: [
      /node_modules\/(?!(your-pkg)\/)/,
    ],
  };
};
```

This transpiles the code for `your-pkg` into `node_modules` dir in `dist`.